# Unable to install Linux font libraries - they freeze when accepting EULA

Tags: linux, fonts

I have tried to build an app in Qt 4.8 While experimenting with rebuilding Qt statically, I installed freetype... though i realize there was already a version installed. Maybe that was the culprit...

Something must have happened to my system fonts... I only have very weird and unusual fonts available to my application. Like Abyssinica SIL - the only font that starts with "A"

Found info about installing them, either with apt-get or even found the deb package

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install msttcorefonts
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/i386/ttf-mscorefonts-installer - for deb package

Either method gives me a EULA with an  at the bottom - which is not clickable - and locks dpkg.

How do I install the fonts and bypass the EULA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accept EULA by pressing TAB which highlighted the 
 `<OK>`